# SQL Server : average column only if it has xxx amount of rows

Tags: sql-server

I'm building out a star rating system for our commerce website and I'm stumped. I can get the average number of stars no problem. But what I'm wanting is for it to only give me the average ***IF there are more that 5 submitted ratings*** for a particular product. By default the database sets everything to 0. So people can only rate between 1-5 stars. So far I have the average:

```
SELECT
    AVG(CAST(review_rating AS numeric(12, 2))) AS avg_rating, ProductID
FROM
    TBLReviews
WHERE 
    review_rating <> 0
GROUP BY 
    ProductID
HAVING  
    (AVG(review_rating) <> 0)
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Where is the "default" of 0 stored? If there's no review I don't understand where you'd find that value or why you need to filter them out.

Comment: By the way you apparently don't need the SQL Server tag.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a simple condition:

```
SELECT  AVG(CAST(review_rating AS numeric(12, 2))) AS avg_rating, 
        ProductID
FROM TBLReviews
WHERE review_rating <> 0
GROUP BY ProductID
HAVING AVG(review_rating) <> 0 
AND COUNT(*) > 5;
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!